# Repeated subtraction of rows from a column using LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sum, subtraction

I would like to repeatedly subtract rows from a column in a table in my database using LINQ. My table is as shown

```
ID       Numbers

1         488  
2         612 
3         803 
4        1082 
5        1310 
6        1586 
7        1899
```

I'd like to take `612` and subtract it with `488` and store the value.

Afterwards take  `803` and subtract it with `612` and store the value.

Do that for every number

```
1082 - 803

1310 - 1082

1586 - 1310

1899 - 1586
```

At the end i'd like to sum the obtained values.

Is there a specific function i could use? I've tried using for loop but i just can't seem to manage to put the pieces together for it to work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple. Just get total sum of `item - previous item`

```
private int GetSumOfSubtractions(int[] numbers)
{
    if (numbers.Length == 0) return 0;
    if (numbers.Length == 1) return numbers[0];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

A little math behind this.

```
612 - 488 + 803 - 612 + 1082 - 803 + 1310 - 1082 + 1586 - 1310 + 1899 - 1586
^           ^^    ^            ^^
```

As you can see middle numbers cancel each other and become 0 and only first item and last item remains.

So `1899-488` is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var numbers = new []
{
    488, 612, 803, 1082, 1310, 1586, 1899,
};

var deltas = numbers.Skip(1).Zip(numbers, (n1, n0) => n1 - n0);

var sum = deltas.Sum();
```

That gives:

```
124 
191 
279 
228 
276 
313
```

With the sum of `1,411`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new []{ 488, 612, 803, 1082, 1310, 1586, 1899 };
var results=array.Last()-array.First();
```

Updated:

Your question can be simplified down to the above.  It will give the correct answer because (x2-x1)+(x3-x2)+(x4-x3)+(x5-x4)+(x6-x5)+(x7-x6) can be simplifed to just -x1+x7 or x7-x1.

Given your original sample set, the answer is `1,411`.

If you want to do it the long way, you can do this:

```
var array = new []{ 488, 612, 803, 1082, 1310, 1586, 1899 };
var results=array.Skip(1).Select((e,i)=>e-array[i]).Sum();
```

You could also do it this way:

```
var array = new []{ 488, 612, 803, 1082, 1310, 1586, 1899 };
var results=array
  .Aggregate(new {prev=array.First(),sum=0},                            // Initialize
    (last,current)=>new {prev=current,sum=last.sum+current-last.prev},  // Repeat
    c=>c.sum);                                                          // Finalize
```

Comment: downvoters must've got 0 mark in math exams. sorry but for a short time i also thought this is not an answer. please explain a little bit!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Unfortunate, but I find those that downvote without a comment usually don't understand the question.  I really wish SO would force a comment if you are going to downvote an answer.

Comment: This should be marked as answer. This solution is really short and sweet.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's a good idea but you can try `LinkedList<T>` class in C#:

```
var numbers = new LinkedList<int>(new[]
                        {
                            488, 612, 803, 1082, 1310, 1586, 1899
                        });
            var sum = 0;
            var node = numbers.First;
            while (node.Next != null)
            {
                var cur = node;
                node = node.Next;
                Console.WriteLine(node.Value - cur.Value);
                sum += node.Value - cur.Value;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("********************");
            Console.WriteLine($"Sum is : {sum}");
```